# How to destructure a struct into another struct containing the same fields?

Tags: rust

How can I make a new struct `B` from `A` without copying all the fields in `A` manually?

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct A {
    field1: i64,
    field2: i64,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct B {
    field1: i64,
    field2: i64,
    field3: i64,
}

fn main() {
    let a = A {
        field1: 10,
        field2: 20,
    };
    let b = B {
        field1: 1,
        field2: 2,
        field3: 3,
    };

    // how can i create c by destructuring a?
    let c = B { field3: 3, ..a };

    println!("{:?}", a);
    println!("{:?}", b);
    println!("{:?}", c);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=84f7d5027f870b1491d3c870848741a8)